# Laravel 5.6 using barryvdh/snappy to create pdf in windows

Tags: pdf-generation, laravel-5.6, laravel-snappy

I am trying to create a PDF in Laravel 5.6 using Barryvdh/snappy. my `config/snappy.php` looks like

```
'pdf' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => 'C:/xampp/htdocs/pdftesting/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => array(),
    'env'     => array(),
),
```

and my controller looks like,

```
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf',$data);
        return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
```

But i get this error,

> The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:\n
>   stderr: "'C:/xampp/htdocs/pdftesting/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\n
>   operable program or batch file.\r\n
>   "\n
>   stdout: ""\n
>   command: C:/xampp/htdocs/pdftesting/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality --images --enable-javascript --javascript-delay "10" "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\knp_snappy5ad430445b31e9.92776484.html" "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\knp_snappy5ad430445fac87.79827170.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

try this solution https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/60 and look for STAMBOULI ABDELKARIM's comment, it worked out for me.

It's hard/impossible to generate charts using DomPDF, it was also pointed out by the developer Barryvdh

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention that if you installed wkhtmltopdf or not on windows. If not visit https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html, download according to your windows requirement (if your windows is 32bit then download 32bit, if 64bit download 64bit msi file) and install it to default location.

Then change your config/snappy.php file according to following line

'binary' => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf"'

Hope this will help you.

for more reference visit
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Comment: @M.aslam hey thanks for the reply, I have actually moved onto using `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` which is much easier to use from what i have seen.

Comment: ok. If you are happy with dompdf then use it. I used dompdf but was not happy with it output. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's a Windows error. Try adding the **Wkhtmltopdf** `bin` folder to the path.
Refer to this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/).

[image: Refer to this image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it if you copy files to public path and edit binary path in config/snappy file

```
        'pdf' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => public_path('wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'),
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],

'image' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => public_path('wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltoimage.exe'),
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],
```

or add double quotes to the bin path for wkhtmltopdf 
'binary' => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf"'